# Regex delete statement

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like:

> [url=www.google.com]www.google.com

I'm new in regex and I don't understand it very well. Can anyone explain or show me how can I delete with regex in that string in order to get this result:

> wwww.google.com

Basically, I want to delete [url=www.google.com]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: no regex is needed. it is just a simple replace `"[url=www.google.com]www.google.com".replace("[url=www.google.com]","")`. Unless your question is to replace everything that is between `[]`

Comment: it's not that simple because instead of [url=www.google.com] I can have any other url there :)

Comment: `"[url=www.google.com]www.google.com".replace(/ *\[[^)]*\] */g, "");` does the job?

Comment: split by "]" and take the second part.

Comment: `"[url=www.google.com]www.google.com".replace(/\[.*\]/g,"");`

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. Also don't get your hopes up about the code, **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service**. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
str.replace(/\[.*\]/, '');
```

Comment: parenthesis will make regex to remember the group therefore will use more memory when it is seems it is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers I was able to find the correct regex. The one that helped me is:

```
str.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, '');
```

I found out that I could had string like this: "[url=http://www.google.com]www.google.com [url=http://www.google.de]www.google.de
and this regex is searching only for this "[url=http://www.google.com]" sequence.

Thank for helping me understand this